# apply attr to the first level

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:">A</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item "><a href="">B</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="page_item "><a href="">C</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

how do I just change the attr for all `<li class="page_item"><a href="javascript:"></a>` but no ul.children.

```
$('li.page_item a').not("ul.children").attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

not working. thanks

Comment: Would the top level `li` not be inside a `ul` or `ol` too? Seeing it would be invalid HTML if it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the top level `ul` a class like `parent` and then :

```
$('ul.parent > li.page_item > a').attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mtAjm/)

Comment: I'm not sure there is a top level `ul`, unless the code given by OP is not complete. Also OP's text seems to imply there isn't. +1 though anyway as there must be a parent `ul` or `ol` for valid HTML.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl if there isn't, the browser will implicitly create it like it creates tbody for example :P But he should create it explicitly anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell: `$("ul:not(.children) > li.page_item > a").attr("href","blah");`. The `:not` jQuery pseudo-selector allows you to filter out the stuff you don't want (ul.children) from your set (ul). From there, direct children li, direct children a.

Hope this helped. If it is still unclear, don't hesitate to comment and I'll elaborate further.

P.S: fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VsL5t/

Comment: +1 but it also assume there is a parent `ul`. There should be one but not sure if OP has one.

Comment: Not having one would break W3C compliance (LI can strictly only be children of a list-type element). I assumed as such because, frankly, HTML4 has been dead & buried for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li.page_item a').not('.children a').attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

edit - or for an even more specific filtering (although the above fills the requirements for answer):

```
$('li.page_item a').not('ul.children li.page_item a').attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

Comment: FYI: as you have written it, each of your `not` calls will execute between 1 (direct li) and however many parentNode calls to get to the root of the DOM. In addition, your function will happily map ul.children -> li -> ul -> li, which is not necessarily what the OP wants/needs. Consider revising.

Comment: +1, though maybe not the most efficient it does select the required `li`, even with the missing outer `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the elements and skip the ones without `.children`.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwM59/1/)**

```
$('li.page_item a').each(function(){
 if( $('.children',this.parentNode).length == 0 ) return true;
 $(this).attr("href","http://www.google.com");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `has` method.

```
$('li.page_item')
         .has("ul.children")
         .children('a')
         .prop("href", "http://google.com");
```

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, I should have used `children` instead of `find`, http://jsfiddle.net/L98TQ/2/

Comment: +1. Selector works great now with given code from OP. Even with the missing `ul`. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

You were close in your attempt. The selector in the `not` call will not match anything as the collection contains `a` elements, and the selector matches `ul` elements. Add `a` to the selector:

```
$('li.page_item a').not("ul.children a").attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the direct descendant selector:

```
$('li.page_item > a').attr("href", "http://google.com");
```

Comment: That will match the child items too.

Comment: Oh yea. I typed before I read. I see now the whole setup is nested with the same structure and class names duplicated. I highly recommend identifying the parent UL like Will.i.am suggests.